# lock the rotation only for a custom modal view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am using a UITabBarController, and my app is supporting portrait and landscape rotations. At launching the app, I am showing up a modal view, but I need that modal view to be fixed to portrait only. I don't know how to go, similar thread hear suggested to subclass and override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations`and `shouldAutorotate`, the controller is `UIViewController` subclass and the modal view is a `UIView` subclass.

Relevant code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

//here I tried to test whether the modal is still visible on the screen and return no in such case, but doesn't seems to work.
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**iOS target: 5.0**

Answer (score 0):

Orientations always confused me, specially the change from iOS5 to iOS6.
Yesterday I did the complete opposite of what you are trying to accomplish. I needed to have only one model view rotate. I've edited my code to fit your needs.

First, select all the orientations you need here:

[image]

In your **rootViewController.m:**

```
//iOS 6
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        return YES;
    }
```

In your **ModelViewController.m:**

```
// iOS5
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

// iOS6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

// iOS6
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return uiinterfaceorientationmaskportrait;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx for that, actually the modal is a `UIView` subclass and not `UIViewController` subclass so I cannot override those method above in the modal class. The modal is simply a view which gets shown up as the launch of the app, I need to lock that view to portrait orientation. The `rootViewController` is the appdelegate is my case where all tabs controllers are initialized. But how about `ModelViewController` ? I tried to consider the first tab controller as the `ModelViewController` like you suggested above and place the code inside, but the modal view still rotate

Comment: If you are talking about locking a UIView you'll need to check the rotation of the ViewController and assign the right x,y,height, width to the view accordingly to every rotation.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I assigned the same frame for portrait,but when the device is rotated to landscape, frame gets changed and the view is rotated

Comment: Post all your code and not just the ViewController rotations part.